# Unable to add bearer token in API client

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, bearer-token

I am trying to add bearer token in the API request but token not added.

Here is my code:

```
object APIClient {

    val client: ApiInterface
        get() {
            val httpLoggingInterceptor =
                HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)


            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${getString(TOKEN, "")}")
                        .build()
                    chain.proceed(request)
                }
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build()

            val retrofit: Retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
}
```

Below I have attacked response image for reference

[image]

I am trying to add bearer token in the API client but it's not added in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**no need to create instance here just need to return retrofit only**

```
object API {
val client: Retrofit
    get() {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${getString(TOKEN, "")}")
                    .build()
                chain.proceed(request)
            }
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .build()

        val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

        return retrofit
    }
```

}